# How to display an object item

Tags: javascript, object

i want to try to display my object item in console with console.log but console shows it as undefined. Can you help me?

```
var myMusic = 
[
  {
    "artist": "Billy Joel",
    "title": "Piano Man",
    "release_year": 1973,
    "formats": [
      "CD",
      "8T",
      "LP"
    ],
    "gold": true
  },
  {
    "artist": "Beau Carnes",
    "title": "Cereal Man",
    "release_year": 2003,
    "formats": [
      "Youtube Video"
  ],
  },    
];

console.log(myMusic.artist);
```

> I am tried that, and i was expected to see `Billy Joel` in console but it wrote `undefined` in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple mistake, check comments in the codeblock, if i can help further, please comment

```
var myMusic = 
[
  {
    "artist": "Billy Joel",
    "title": "Piano Man",
    "release_year": 1973,
    "formats": [
      "CD",
      "8T",
      "LP"
    ],
    "gold": true
  },
  {
    "artist": "Beau Carnes",
    "title": "Cereal Man",
    "release_year": 2003,
    "formats": [
      "Youtube Video"
  ],
  },    
];

console.log(myMusic.artist); // undefined because myMusic is an array
console.log(myMusic[0].artist); // "Billy Joel"
console.log(myMusic[1].artist); // "Beau Carnes"
console.log(myMusic[0]) /* 
{
    "artist": "Billy Joel",
    "title": "Piano Man",
    "release_year": 1973,
    "formats": [
      "CD",
      "8T",
      "LP"
    ],
    "gold": true
  } */
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. But in the lesson video, it says it is an object. Actually is it not object?

Comment: It is an array, but the items in the array are objects :)

Comment: You can fetch the items in the array with bracket notations like so: array[0] (First item), array[1] (second item) and so on

In objects you can get the values by dot notation or brackets that takes a string
object.property // 'value'
object['property'] // 'value'

Comment: @Kjetil please don't order users to accept your answer. That's not how this site works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant it as a request, but I see how it can be taken as an order
Thanks for letting me know, @Andy